# SpriteKit problems with SKScene

Tags: ios, performance, sprite-kit

I have performance problems using iOS Sprite kit.

I did the main scene of the game and every thing run nice and smoothly, then I inserted a splash windows in the beginning and when I change the scene to the main scene the game seems laggy with frame drop, but fps, cpu and memory parameters are Ok.

I also have a game over screen and the behaviour is the same, when the game return to the main scene looks very laggy.

I have tried with [self removeFromParents] and removing children, and nothing happens.

Code:

```
@implementation Splash
- (id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{

if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {


    SKSpriteNode *sprite= [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"main"];
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(160,284);
    [self addChild:sprite];



       }
return self;
}
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Transition back to the Game
    SKScene *myScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:myScene transition:reveal];
    [self removeAllChildren];
    [self removeAllActions];
    [self removeFromParent];
}
@end
```

Comment: Please be more specific. "seems/looks laggy", "fps, cpu, memory are OK" only vaguely describe what's happening. For how long does the lag persist? What does "OK" mean (60 fps)? Did you test on an actual device?  What code runs when you create MyScene? PS: when you present a scene, you do *not need* to explicitly remove nodes/actions from the scene.

Comment: Hi, fps 60. But the game runs very laggy, seem that loose some frames, but the fps counter shows 60 on my device (4c)

Comment: The most common cause is that your code does something periodically that takes a long time to finish. Loading resource files, or creating many nodes in a single frame can cause one frame to take longer than others without affecting the average framerate (much).

Comment: Thanks, but the code on the main (game) scene runs fine, the problem is when another scene run after. It seems a bug on SK or something with the SKScene that I'm missing.

Comment: 100% sure (rounded to nearest integer) it's not a Sprite Kit bug. Possibly your game scene doesn't deallocate, keeps running. If you use GCD, performSelector or NSTimer it's even possible that it runs (some) game logic in the background.

Comment: When the game doesn't run smooth on the debugger I see some threads running  in __workq_kernreturn  _pthread_wqthread state and doing nothing with my code. I see that threads only after another scene runs. I add a NSlog on dealloc method it's called.

Comment: It only happens on 8.1 sdk, in 7.1 or less work without problems.

Comment: I'm having similar problems.  No matter what I do to try and force deallocation, it appears it doesn't get called for a SKScene.(I've added the NSLog in the dealloc method)   This is definitely more of a problem in OS8 then OS7.